# Collection view scroll items only

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have collection view, where each cell is actually a table view that fetch whole screen. I want to scroll only to next table (it placed horizontally). So, I want that at any time only one table is on screen. So, when user swipe to right, scroll view change it contents to hide current table view and show another.

I can get that behaviour by implement gesture recognizer and change scroll view contentOffset manually, but I suppose there is an easy way to do that.

How to achieve behaviour I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable paging on your CollectionView if each cell of CollectionView covers whole width of collectionView.

[image]

Finally If you wanna do it without enabling pagination, then you can create a subclass of UICollectionView layout

```
class YourCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

        override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
            var offsetAdjustment = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude

            let horizontalOffset = proposedContentOffset.x + 5 //your cell inset
            let targetRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: 0), size: self.collectionView!.bounds.size)

            for layoutAttributes in super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect)! {
                let itemOffset = layoutAttributes.frame.origin.x
                if (abs(itemOffset - horizontalOffset) < abs(offsetAdjustment)) {
                    offsetAdjustment = itemOffset - horizontalOffset
                }
            }

            return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustment, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
        }
    }
```

Comment: correct answer is simply -         self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
but thanks)

Comment: @evgeniy-kleban : Am glad u solved the problem :) happy coding